Are there any work-arounds for the image transition problem with Safari
I as struggling to find a work-around the Safari "limitation" that stops this fading in and out the images as they change...
  html { 
    background: url(https://www.cw109eu.uk/cover1.webp) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-transition: background 2000ms ease-in-out 2000ms;
    -moz-transition: background 2000ms ease-in-out 2000ms;
    -o-transition: background 2000ms ease-in-out 2000ms;
    transition: background 2000ms ease-in-out 2000ms;
  }

On Edge and Chrome the background images fade in and out nicely, but on Safari it the fading doesn't happen and I get a white blank screen in between images.
I have a CodePen available that shows my code and the effect.  Try it on Edge or Chrome then on Safari and you will see what I mean - https://codepen.io/PhilCorley/pen/QWRExWd#
Can anyone help with how to fix this so it works on all modern browsers?
I would have expected Safari to conform with other browsers, which it doesn't :-(

The standard is that backgrond-image animation is discrete not continuous. See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image so Edge/Chrome is the outlier here. There are several workarounds, involving pseudo elements for example. Have a bit of a search around SO.

You may create a GIF and use it as background image.

Thanks guys.
This isn't the answer but it fixed my problem.  I basically moved away from doing it with CSS and went for a full Javascript solution which works very well on all modern browsers.
